# Extract blocks of lines with sed

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing

How would one go about with sed to extract *n* lines of a file every *m*-th line?

Say my textfile looks like this:

myfile.dat:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Say that I want to extract blocks of three lines and then skipping two lines throughout the entire file, such that my output looks like this:

output.dat:

```
1
2
3
6
7
8
```

Any suggestions on how one could achieve this with sed?

Edit:

For my example I could just have used

sed -n 'p;n;p;n;p;n;n' myfile.dat > output.dat

or with GNU sed (not preferred due to portability)

sed '1~5b;2~5b;3~5b;d' myfile.dat > output.dat

However, I typically want to print blocks of 2450 lines from a file with 49 002 450 lines, such that my outputfile contains 247 450 lines.

Comment: please add what you've tried.. you are getting downvotes because you haven't added research effort... if you are new to sed, check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources...

Comment: there's probably a duplicate to this question somewhere... here's a cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325985/how-to-print-lines-number-15-and-25-out-of-each-50-lines

Comment: It works for my example, however it would be rather inconvenient in the general case where n and m are large.

Comment: `2450` - are they consecutive lines? what is `m` for this case? for consecutive lines, awk would be better suited: `awk -v n=3 -v m=5 '(NR-1)%m < n'`

Comment: Great, thanks! awk does indeed appear to better suited for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '1~5,+2p' file
```

Starting at line 1, print line numbers with modulus 5 and the following two lines.

An alternative:

```
sed -n 'N;N;p;n;n' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however with your first suggestion I get the error message: sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `+'

Comment: just a typo, should be `sed -n '1~5,+2p'`

Answer (score 0):

In your case the below would work.  It's checking the remainder when divided by 5 is between 1 and 3:

```
awk 'NR%5==1, NR%5==3' myfile.dat
```

Comment: Interesting but where NC come from ?  I find nothing about that in the man page

Comment: ctac_ and Sundeep you're both right - this worked only because each of his lines had incremental numbers on.  I've edited my answer to replace `$NC` with `NR` as suggested.